# Embed Frameworks Flutter IO

Tags: ios, flutter

I saw this on my git diff as REMOVED lines:

```
5B24AE652364AC44009D1E32 /* Flutter.framework in Embed Frameworks */,
3B80C3951E831B6300D905FE /* App.framework in Embed Frameworks */,
```

I think I once saw somewhere that App.framework must be in Embed Frameworks, but the app is building fine.

Flutter Version: 1.17 - stable latest

Do you know if this may cause a problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit worried as I had ios build issues after upgrading flutter.